# Keycloak realm role attributes aren't inherited by users

Tags: keycloak

I created a realm-role called `ObjectManager` and added an attribute to that role so that every User having this role would inherit this specific attribute.

[image: realm-role-attribute]

Now I would like to have access to that attribute in my java-application so I tried to add the `area` attribute as `claim` in my token by using a `protocol mapper`. However the `realm-role` attribute is simply not added to my token? (Simple user `attributes/group` attributes are added, but not role attributes)
Am I missing something?
Here is my mapper config

[image: mapper config]

Comment: Please have a look this https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-February/017122.html this is JS but same can be achieve with Java as well.

Comment: Any update on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

User Attribute mapper only maps attributes from user and the groups that user belongs to. This is not clear from the documentation. When you look in to code at the implementation of [UserAttributeMapper](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/31260d011c040360f6465896108fff211f324943/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/mappers/UserAttributeMapper.java#L101C56-L101C56) and [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/31260d011c040360f6465896108fff211f324943/server-spi-private/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/utils/KeycloakModelUtils.java#L686-L707), it is clear that it uses only user and group attributes

You need to implement custom protocol mapper and this mapper to default dedicated mappers of the client. For reference you can see this [repo](https://github.com/frank-fegert/keycloak-script-provider/tree/main)